Delete lines between "GOOD1 bad" and ";"
How can I use a sed command to find and delete the line starting with GOOD1 bad till the end of line (;) semicolon? Example:
Before
LUCK bad (
.abc(abc),
.bcd(bcd),
.def(def));
GOOD1 bad (
.abc(abc),
.bcd(bcd),
.def(def));

After
LUCK bad (
.abc(abc),
.bcd(bcd),
def));

I have tried sed -i -e {s/GOOD1 bad//g} filename.txt but does not seem to work. Probably the items I am trying to replace in the file, is in different line.

Why is .def( gone?

Try simply: sed -e '/GOOD1 bad/,/;/d' -i filename.txt

In case semicolon could be located on same line than 1st pattern (GOOD1 bad), then you could use: sed '/GOOD1 bad/{:_;/;/!{N;b_};d}' -i filename.txt

I tried the 1st command 'sed -e '/GOOD1 bad/,/;/d' and basically empty out the entire file. Is there any other command in shell scripting I can use? The file I am trying to post process, has more than 1 GOOD1. It has many 'GOOD1 bad' repeats itself in the file.
